# how to perform a "shear" action in sketch?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, sketch-app

Adobe Illustrator has a [shear tool](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/scaling-shearing-distorting-objects.html).. is there something equivalent in sketch or at least a series of steps that can achieve the same result?

Answer (score 2):

You can shear items using the transform tool.

- Select the item you want to shear.
- Click the transform tool (or Command + Shift + T)
- Select and hold the top, middle selection point, hold down Option and drag left or right.

You can do the same from any other selection point allowing you to shear vertically (or skew if you drag the corners).